# About apache nifi: is there a flowfile pipeline between endpoints on internet?

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

The request is transfer flowfile to a remote nifi server in a FIFO queue. I have tried methods below:

1. via http
   InvokeHttp -> ListenHttp. I found that there are few requests has been abandoned, and i notice that i can link "retry" to InvokeHttp itself, but i'm not sure whether the flowfile is still at the top of queue or not.
2. via ftp
   PutFtp -> GetFtp. On the get side, the files seems not a FIFO order.

Is there any solutions for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NiFi can accept remote data in a variety of ways -- listening to HTTP requests, consuming TCP/UDP packets, consuming Kafka topics/queues, (S)FTP, AMQP, etc.

If you specifically want to transmit a flowfile from one NiFi instance to another, the [Site-to-Site (S2S) protocol](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#site-to-site) is designed explicitly for this. It makes it very easy to do this. There is even a Java module you can consume in other projects to take advantage of these transmission mechanics.

Comment: Thanks Andy! That's exactly what i need!